# RecyclerView in xamarin .axml file not recognized

Tags: android, visual-studio, android-layout, xamarin.android

I am trying to use RecyclerView in Visual Studio for android development but in .axml it is not recognized.Can you help me with the same. I have downloaded the nuget package for RecyclerView. It detects recyclerview in the cs part but not in the .axml part. Please help.

[image: Please find the error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my experience with the Visual Studio .axml editor, these warnings will show up when using a support library widget directly inside of a LinearLayout or RelativeLayout. However, they do not usually affect the ability to build and run the code.

In the following code, the SwipeRefreshLayout has the same warning you are getting, while the RecyclerView inside of the ViewSwitcher does not. If the RecyclerView was moved up into the LinearLayout, it would show the same warning but the code would still compile properly.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/very_light_gray">
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/swipeRefreshLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/middle_gray">
    <ViewSwitcher
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/switcher"
        android:background="@color/middle_gray">
        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/paperworkRecyclerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_empty"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="No Load Offers Available"
            android:background="@color/middle_gray"
            android:gravity="center" />
    </ViewSwitcher>
</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

If you are having issues building or running the code, make sure you have matching versions of the RecyclerView support package and the Support.v4 package that it depends on and give more information about the error you get at build/run.